# how to prevent user from accessing webpage directly in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response.redirect

Hello I am having an issue preventing a user from accessing my site by typing in the URL. I have a login which I want to be the only way to access my `/factory/homepage.html` page.
But if a user types `/factory/homepage.html` into the URL field, they can access the homepage.html.
Im already using `app.get('/factory/')`, but my `res.redirect('/website/userLogin.html')` does not redirect to the login page.
Here is my code:

```
app.get('/factory/*', function(req,res,next){
   console.log("going through app.get...");
   res.redirect('../website/userLogin.html');
   console.log('after redirect...');
});
```

The output is:

```
going through app.get...
after redirect...
```

And the user is taken to `factory/homepage.html`.  I also tried `app.use('/factory/*')`, but no luck. The redirecting only works if a path that doesn't exist in my factory directory is entered, for example `/factory/hello.html` will redirect to `/website/userLogin.html`

I'll like for the directory `/factory` to not be accessible through typing in the url. Then after i will implement a middleware function to check if the user is authenticated.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hopefully I do not misunderstand you.. but I think the solution is a matter of simple authentication. You can just set up an app.get(index) and check if the request is authenticated, if not, redirect to some other page?

Comment: If you are checking if they are logged in or not, why does it matter if they visit the login page before the other page? Why isn't the authentication enough?

Comment: Possibly related: [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

Comment: @fzxt The issue I'm having is the redirecting, redirect only works if the path doesn't exists in my directory. If the correct path name is entered the redirect doesn't work and the user is taken directly to the page.

Comment: @Quentin If i find that a user is not authenticated my redirect to any other page doesn't work if they type in the correct path.

Comment: @HFernando — Then you should look into fixing that problem instead of trying to build a workaround that depends on weird assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this.

```
app.get('/factory/*', function(req,res,next){

   var authenticated = false;

   //do something to authenticate user

   if(authenticated === true){
       //user is already authenticated
       res.redirect('/factory/homepage.html');
   }else{
       //redirect to login
       res.redirect('../website/userLogin.html');
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I still am taken directly to the /factory/homepage.html page. The else code is executed since authenticated equals false but res.redirect does not execute.

Comment: Replace `//do something to authenticate user` with a function that to change `authenticated` to `true` if the user has been authenticated.